# Removing buttons from plotly modebar

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to remove the orbit rotation button in the plotly modebar from a scatter3D plot. According to [the manual (26.3 Remove modebar buttons by name)](https://plotly-r.com/control-modebar.html) it sounds feasible. However when I try it out the plot vanishes. Regular scatter3d plot:

```
fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig
```

[image]

But when I try to remove the button using the list of names [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js) the plot vanishes (and so does the modebar) :

```
fig %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("orbitRotation"))
```

[image]

It seems to work for some buttons but not others - is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails if only a single button is to be removed. [See this github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1433). If you put the button name into a list it should work:

```
fig %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = list("orbitRotation"))
```